# R - Como calcular a densidade a partir da curva acumulada com base no Modelo de regressão Cox

Tags: r

Calculei a probabilidade acumulada (em inglês, cdf) dos meus dados, me baseando na probabilidade de excedência (em inglês,edf), usando o modelo de regressão Cox. Até ai ok, sem problema algum.

Porém, alguém sabe se existe algum comando para transformar esses dados na densidade de probabilidade (em inglês, pdf)?

Já testei usando pela função do histograma, mas não funciona corretamente.

```
dado1<-c(128.1072, 124.2218, 127.5064, 143.5201, 121.6476, 121.4071, 133.5725, 127.9324, 115.7151, 131.6176, 113.7500, 122.2064, 133.9970, 125.4781, 122.9766, 132.7081, 124.9619, 134.4549, 127.4127, 121.9021, 111.9924, 122.4483, 132.1261, 129.7735,124.7136, 118.2293, 120.5072, 129.5527, 125.7787)

dado2<-c(174.07874, 132.74495, 84.52224, 82.93248, 113.13792, 112.87297, 163.48032, 170.10432, 184.41215, 169.30945, 152.35201, 127.44576, 130.62528, 123.20640, 59.61600, 48.75264, 77.10335, 113.93281, 83.99231, 164.27521, 111.81314, 72.06912, 169.04448, 229.45537, 79.48800,  57.23136,  72.33408, 95.38560, 136.18944)

dado3<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

dado4<-c(1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010)

dados<-data.frame(cbind(dado4,dado2,dado1,dado3))

require(survival)

curva <- coxph(Surv(dados[,2], dados[,4]) ~ dados[,3], dados)
a<-summary(curva)
coef<-as.numeric(data.frame(a$coef[1]))

edf<-survfit(curva)$surv
edf<-append(1,edf)
cdf<-1-edf

ano<-12
prevcox<-edf^exp(coef*dados[ano,3])
```

Quero encontrar a pdf, me baseando na cdf e edf encontrada, para a variável prevcox.

Comment: Para densidades empíricas talvez densidades do núcleo, que podem ser calculadas com `density(x)`. Veja a página de ajuda `?density` para os vários núcleos disponíveis. Para obter os valores de `x` e de `y` pode ser com `pdf <- density(x); pdf$x; pdf$y`.

Comment: Obrigada @RuiBarradas!
Porém, quando fui testar sua sugestão, apresentou um erro.
"Erro em pdf$x: objeto de tipo 'closure' não possível dividir em subconjuntos".
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Deve ser porque `pdf` já é o nome de uma função R base e por vezes há conflitos de nomes. Tente só `f`, assim: `f <- density(x); f$x; f$y`.

Comment: Agora sim, obrigada @RuiBarradas!

Comment: porque você está usando análise de sobrevivência se o seu dado não apresenta nenhuma censura?

Comment: você tem certeza que quer encontrar a pdf baseado na cdf? Pois em modelos de sobrevivência, normalmente utilizam-se as funções de sobrevivência e risco acumulado para interpretar o modelo

Answer (score 1):

Se tais valores são o resultado da sua F(x), então você pode aproximar sua fdp(x) a partir da seguinte equação:

[image: fórmula]

em que x2 e x1 são os valores de "x" que você utilizou para calcular a sua F(x), em que x2>x1, mas a diferença entre x2 e x1 deve ser próxima de zero, para que você possa assumir, por exemplo que a equação acima resulte em fdp(x2).

Em código R, você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
F_para_fdp <- function(x1, x2, Fx2, Fx1){
  return((Fx2-Fx1)/(x2-x1))
}
```

Comment: Obrigada @GuilhermeParreira! Porém, acho que não consegui fazer funcionar. Indiquei quem seria meu x1 e meu x2, e rodei exatamente como escreveu acima. Aparentemente roda, mas não obtenho nenhum resultado. E quando digito "F_para_fdp", volta exatamente todas as linhas que escrevi.

Comment: Por nada Iara! A função que eu coloquei é apenas para iniciar o processo...
 Note que os valores que você colocou na pergunta são o resultado da F(x), e não os valores de "x". Para eu lhe fornecer uma resposta completa, preciso que você forneça os valores de "x".

Comment: Guilherme Parreira, respondi aqui no post para ficar mais detalhado. Obrigada!

Comment: Olá @iara, você deveria editar o texto e o título da sua questão, e não colocar como uma resposta. Pois da forma que a questão foi feita, ela é bem genérica, e aí a minha resposta cabe, mas no seu caso você precisa disso no contexto do modelo de Cox. Semana que vem provavelmente eu irei estudar tal modelo, e poderei fornecer uma resposta aqui para você!!

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme Parreira! Acreditei que conseguiria descobrir daquela outra maneira. Mas reescrevi a questão para que ficasse claro.